# Jquery: get birthday value from page and substitute with age value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a `jsp` having a table with users info and there's a column representing user's birthday in format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I want to substitute those birth dates with actual age of user.
So I have simple JS function getAge for it:

```
    function getAge(dateString) {
        var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

I've tried to run it after page initializing in that way:

```
$().ready(function({
    $(".age").html(getAge($(this).html()));
}));
```

where `.age` is a class of "Age" column. So that's the way I expected it to work:

`$(".age")` - finds cell with class="age"

`$(".age").html(getAge($(this).html()));` - substitues html in found cell with value returned from getAge() function where argument for getAge is current value in that cell.
but it shows nothing =(

If I use smthg like this for testing:

`$(".age").html(getAge("1960-08-15"));`- it works correctly and substitutes birthdays in all rows with age calculated from 1960-08-15 =)

maybe I don't understand what `$(this)` returns in my context? I was sure it should return current element which I just invoked with my selector (cell)

Could you give me a hint?

thx a lot

Comment: Is the date string directly in the cell, or is it wrapped by something? could you please try with  `$(".age").html(getAge($(this).text()));`

Comment: @Spokey html row is <tr><td>admin</td><td class = "age">1980-08-08</td></tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through each age and set their html using jquery .each

```
$(".age").each(function(){....});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Yyene/